# Colocando cabeçalho em arquivo CSV

Tags: php, csv, log, header

Tenho na página de um cliente uma rotina de geração de log. Contudo, preciso acrescentar sempre na primeira linha um campo de cabeçalho. Eis o código da função:

```
public function generateLogPMWeb($action){
    session_start('usuario');
    $logPMWeb  = $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . "_" . $_POST['idHotel'] . "_" . date('YmdHis') . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['nome'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['sobrenome'] . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['email'] . ";" . "IC"
            . ";" . $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . "_" . $_POST['idHotel'] . "_" . date('YmdHis') . ";" . $_POST['idHotel'] . ";" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ";" . $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'] . ";" . $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataFim']
            . ";" . "Acao: " .  preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', $action) . ";\n";
    file_put_contents(Config::retorna("document_root", "root").'/logs/logPMWeb_'.date("Ymd").'.csv', $logPMWeb, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Já olhei em outros sites o uso da função fputcsv, mas não sei ela serve pra esse caso. O é melhor de se fazer?

Comment: O que faz a função `Config::retorna`? Poste o código se não for gigante

Comment: Não achei o código, mas acredito que é pra configurar a raiz de diretório onde o arquivo CSV vai ser inserido.